# Error when setting the date of setissue

Tags: hapi-fhir

I am getting the error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;

while setting the date of setIssued in HAPI FHIR Observation.

I have added commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar in the class path. 
Please help me to resolve this issue.

List of jars in class path :
activation-1.1.1.jar,antlr-2.7.6.jar,asm-3.1.jar,cglib-2.2.jar,commons-collections-3.1.jar,commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar,dom4j-1.6.1.jar,gson-2.2.4.jar,hapi-fhir-base-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,hapi-fhir-structures-dstu-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,hapi-fhir-structures-dstu2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,hibernate-annotations.jar,hibernate-commons-annotations.jar,hibernate-entitymanager.jar,hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar,hibernate-tools.jar,hibernate3.jar,jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar,jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar,jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar,javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar,javassist.jar,javax.json-1.0.4.jar,javax.json-api-1.0.jar,jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar,jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar,jersey-bundle-1.16.jar,jersey-client-1.16.jar,jersey-core-1.16.jar,jersey-json-1.16.jar,jersey-server-1.16.jar,jettison-1.1.jar,joda-time-1.5.2.jar,JSON-java.jar,log4j-1.2.17.jar,quartz-2.1.5.jar,slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar,stax-api-1.0-2.jar,struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.12.jar,struts2-core-2.3.12.jar,struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.8.jar,xwork-core-2.3.12.jar

Comment: Can you also check if there are multiple(similar) jars in the classpath ?